# Storing Kinect Data on a USB Drive

Tags: kinect, ros

Does anybody know if Kinect Data can be stored directly onto a USB Drive?? 
I have a Kinect for Windows that i cannot use on Linux(ROS). However what i plan is to mount the Kinect on my robot, store the captured frames on a USB and then un mount the USB ,transfer to Linux and process them on ROS.

Is this possible?? Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use it on Linux? As far as I am aware, it is basically the same as the Kinect for XBox.

Comment: NO they are not the same and the K4W is not identified on Linux at all.

Comment: Again, I don't have one to test, but you should try the links in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can Kinect data be stored directly onto a USB drive?**

Yes. In ROS that would be easily done using bag files. In Windows, however, you might have to look for something native in the Microsoft SDK/OpenNI or code it yourself. *Edit: In OpenNI there is something called .oni files for that purpose.*

**The implicit question: Does Kinect for Windows work in Linux?**

As far as I am aware, yes. From what I researched there were [compatibility issues with OpenNI initially](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/fFJM0DqLWq4) but [they seem to be solved](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/fFJM0DqLWq4) as of May 2012. There are reports of users successfully using K4W in both Windows and Linux there. See [this previous question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/654/what-is-the-difference-between-kinect-for-windows-and-kinect-for-xbox) for more info.

I assume the changes have made their way upstream, but the only way to be sure is to test it. If they haven't, you can always use the patched version referred in the link.

**Conclusion**

My suggestion is get your sensor working in Linux and don't waste your time trying to figure out how to save Kinect data to a USB drive in Windows.