# whitch kind of kinect should i buy

Tags: ros, kinect, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,i want to buy a kinect to control the NAO robot,there are two kinds of kinect i can but:1,kinect for xbox360.2,kinect for windows.
i want to use openni and kinect to develop a application to control the NAO.is there anyone know whitch kind of the kinect should buy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98211/whitch-kind-of-kinect-should-i-buy/) by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say go for the XBOX360 Kinect, since it's widely used in the ROS community and [some people report problems getting the Kinect for Windows to work with ROS](http://answers.ros.org/question/12876/kinect-for-windows/).

PS: IMO the [ASUS Xtion Pro Live](http://www.asus.com/Multimedia/Xtion_PRO_LIVE/) is an even better choice, since it only requires an USB connection, is smaller and lighter and has the same performance as the Kinect. Unfortunately, it is usually a bit more expensive.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on 2013-11-08**:
is the problem (kinect for windows )serious?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-08**:
I included a link to the Q&A on how to get the Kinect for Windows to work with ROS in my answer. Seems like a bit of work to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may help in your decision

[What is the difference between Kinect for Windows and Kinect for XBox?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/660)

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This really isn't the kind of question that that ROSAnswers is designed for.  From the FAQ:

What kinds of questions can I ask here?

Most importantly - questions should be relevant to this community. Before you ask - please make sure to search for a similar question. You can search questions by their title or tags.

What kinds of questions should be avoided?

Please avoid asking questions that are not relevant to this community, too subjective and argumentative.

To give an answer for your question, it would benefit you to research what the NAO Robot community specifically uses.  If this is going to be the primary use of the device, that specific subset of the community probably has found that one is more compatible than the other.

For customization, I would lean more towards the Xbox version rather than the SDK edition.

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-11-07**:
Slightly disagreeing here. The question could be better phrased, but it still sounds to me like he is asking, which is the best Kinect version to be used with ROS - a valid question for ROS Answers in my opinion.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-08**:
Fair enough.  It was partly a knee-jerk reaction to the typing errors which I later realized might just be a communication issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree this is not really the place, but with that being said, I would strongly recommend you the Xbox360 version, unless you don't want to use ROS.
Some (advanced) modifications have to be made to manage to use windows kinect with ROS.

Moreover, please note there are two models of kinect for Xbox360. The last model can have some drawbacks if you are a very advanced user trying to do multiple kinects on the same computer.
(see [this topic](http://answers.ros.org/question/61542/kinect-xbox360-new-model-1473-has-problems-example-serial-number-soundcard/) if you want to know a bit more about it)
However, for most people, the two models of kinects for 360 are not different, as they are both recognized in ROS.

Have a good day,

Bests regards

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-13**:
Well that sucks... I've been using three 1473's at once without issue in ROSHydro.  Hope problems don't come up when I get to more advanced techniques like multiplexing.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-11-14**:
The problems appear only if you want to use some things, like calling the kinect by serial for example. For most applications, it doesn't change anything (which explains that there is NO documentation for this model...)
Have a good day !

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-08**:
I just realized this might be my current issue.  If it doesn't have a serial number, does that mean that intrinsic calibrations cannot be saved?  And moreso, does that mean that I cannot use packages like camera_pose_calibration since they require this?  I am trying to combine frames from 3 Kinects.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2014-01-08**:
Try to do the intrisic calibrations, and you will see if they are saved or not, and let us know.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-09**:
I have one from the 1414 model, and one from both of the 1473's. Both of the 0000.yaml files(rgb and depth) are from the first 1473 I calibrated (Kinect 2).  My 3rd Kinect's calibration didn't overwrite either one.  Even so, shouldn't camera_pose_calibration just call the 0000.yaml files twice?

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2014-01-12**:
Yes probably... I am sorry, but right now, I am unsure of what your problem really is. You should open a new thread explaining exactly what works, what doesn't, and what are the outputs (and your config).
Bests regards